# mysql update from another table if fields are not equal

Tags: mysql, sql

what's wrong with this query?

```
update TA,TB
set TA.change = 1,TA.value = TB.value
where
TA.name  = TB.name and TA.value <> TB.value
```

I want to update TA from TB when value change in TB

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: name is uniqe, and value is not NULL.
I want to update rows with same name and different values, but query dont do it

Answer (score 0):

Your query is okay.  I would write it with an explicit `join`:

```
update TA join
       TB
       on TA.name  = TB.name
     set TA.change = 1,
         TA.value = TB.value
where TA.value <> TB.value;
```

You might need to take `NULL` values into account:

```
update TA join
       TB
       on TA.name  = TB.name
     set TA.change = 1,
         TA.value = TB.value
where not (TA.value <=> TB.value);
```

Comment: thanks, but it give me an error because of "on" and without it , not work yet!

Comment: @shmosel . . . In MySQL, probably not because it does not log updates that do not change records.  However, some databases do log updates even when nothing changes, so I usually add a check.